# Why do i get a error when i try to define these three constructors? Examples given

Tags: java, methods

Okay so the problem is, NetBeans is saying the second one is already defined. These three are my constructors  at the top, The whole program is listed in case a set or get method is the error of it. So to be clear i am talking about

public Dog(String initialName)
public Dog(String initialBreed)
public Dog(double initialWeight)

The error shows up on public Dog(String initialBreed). Did i misuse the Overload method? Also i must use the overload method it is mandatory.

```
package dog;


import java.util.*;
public class Dog 
{

// instance variables
private String name;
private String breed;
private double weight;

 public Dog( )
{
name = "no name";
breed = "no breed";
weight = 0.0;
}

public Dog(String initialName)
{
name = initialName;
breed = "no breed";
weight = 0.0;
     }

public Dog(String initialBreed){
   name = "no name";
   breed = initialBreed;
   weight = 0.0;
 }
public Dog(double initialWeight){
    name = "no name";
    breed = "no breed";
    weight = initialWeight;
     }


  public void SetDog(String newName, String newBreed, double newWeight) 
  {
   name = newName;
   breed = newBreed;
   if (newWeight <= 0)
      System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
   else
       weight = newWeight;
    }
public void setName(String newName){
    name = newName;
}
public void setBreed(String newBreed){
    breed = newBreed;
}
public void setWeight(double newWeight){
    weight = newWeight;
}

public double getWeight(){
     return weight;
}
public String getName(){
     return name;
}
public String getBreed(){
    return breed;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that two of your constructors take the same argument:

```
public Dog(String initialName)

public Dog(String initialBreed){
```

They both take `string`. You can't have two methods with the exact same name and parameters.

Based on what I think you are trying to do, you might want a single constructor that takes all 3 of those parameters:

```
public Dog(String initialName, String initialBreed, double initialWeight){
```

Comment: Ah i see, i am required for the assignment to use the overload method for all three constructors, am i missing something or is it just not possible with two Strings. If i cannot use two strings than i do not think i can make it this way right?

Comment: Correct, you're probably missing the bigger picture since this current approach will not work. EDIT: If you could explain a little better what you're trying to do, we might be able to help.

Comment: //This constructor sets the name of the Dog object to the argument initialName, it then sets the other 2 //instance variables to default values.
public Dog (String initialName)
{
 name = initialName;
 breed = “no breed”;
 weight = 0.0;
}

Write the rest of the constructors, the headers for these constructors are shown below: 
//public Dog (String initialName, String initialBreed, double initialweight)
//public Dog (String initialBreed)
//public Dog (double initialweight)

Comment: Those are the instructions, i understand that it cannot be used. overload needs different parameters in order to distinguish between each constructor. Possibly that was the lesson.

Comment: That could be it. Then explain clearly the situation that you need different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dog(String initialName)
{
name = initialName;
breed = "no breed";
weight = 0.0;
}

public Dog(String initialBreed){
name = "no name";
breed = initialBreed;
weight = 0.0;
}
```

The above two constructor which you defined are not overloaded properly as both are having same header with same type and numbers of arguments.